# Form submission with optional children and validation

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I think I have an issue with validation, one to one relationships and partial form submissions.

Here's the scenario:

I have the following entities:

- `Opportunity`
- `Deal`
- `PaymentPreferences`

with the following relationships:

- `Opportunity` has one `Deal`
- `Opportunity` has one `PaymentPreferences`

I also have the following forms to match the entity relationship:

- `OpportunityType` that has a child `DealType` and `PaymentPreferencesType`

Here's where it gets tricky…

- `Opportunity->paymentPreferences` is optional
- If `Opportunity->paymentPreferences` is not null then `PaymentPreferences` has a required attribute: `numberOfPayments`

I need:

- to create an API where an `Opportunity` can be submitted with a `Deal` but without `PaymentPreferences`
- to create a front end form where the `PaymentPreferences` can be added

So…

From the API side I think this can be solved using an event listener on the form. If there's no `PaymentPreference` in the submitted data don't add the `PaymentPreferencesType` to the `OpportunityType` form. Sound ok?

On the front end side I think I need some kind of button to "Add Payment Preferences". I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or how I would add it. If this was a one to many relationship I could use the `CollectionType` with allow_add and allow_remove.

I'm running Symfony3.

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006240/optional-embed-form-in-symfony-2

Comment: Apparently I tried to find an answer to this issue in 2011: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/symfony2/_VpzT-Rsx7A/YfmUibHea00J

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

- Always add your subform `PaymentPreferencesType` to your main form.
- Add a field "active" to your entity `PaymentPreferences`
- On the front side, with a button or a checkbox, allow user to show or hide the fields for `PaymentPreferences`, (don't forget to reset the fields when the subform is hidden -ie. `$('#paymentPreferences_numberOfPayments').val('').` )

Then in your entity `PaymentPreferences` instead of using nullable=false on your numberOfPayments field, just use something like

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 *  @Assert\IsTrue(message="Please indicate the number of payments")
 */
public function isValid()
{
    return $this->active == null || ($this->active != null && $this->numberOfPayments != null)
}
```

Comment: I was thinking possible validation groups as well.