# Symfony 3: Embedded form whole or nothing validation error display

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I have the exactly same problem as described here: [Optional embed form in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12006240/715660):

I have a form for the entity *Person* that has an embedded form for the entity *Phone*. The user can leave all fields of *Phone* empty and the form will be valid. But if a single field of *Phone* was filled-in, all *Phone*-fields must be valid.

During my first approach, I simply annotated the *Phone* property of *Person* with `@Assert\Valid()` without `@Assert\NotNull()`. That works fine only when entering a new *Person*. When editing an existing *Person* and the *Phone* property was already filled-in, the deletion of all *Phone* fields (which should be valid) does not result into a valid submit.

The validation of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762361/715660)  with a validation callback function works with some modifications for Symfony 3:

```
/**
 *
 * @Assert\Callback()
 */
public function validatePhone(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if (/* Fields are not empty */)
    {
       $context->getValidator()->inContext($context)->validate($this->phone);
    }
}
```

But after submitting the form, validation errors for the phone fields are not shown on the page. I can only see them in the debug toolbar.

Maybe, this solution needs to be modified somehow, to let the errors be displayed after form submission?

But maybe even my first approach might work, if it is somehow possible to set the property *Phone* of an existing *Person* object to null, if all form fields of *Phone* have been cleared?

Answer (score 0):

try to use cascade_validation ([be carefull removed from symfony3](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/collection.html#cascade-validation)) and error_bubbling in your formType class

```
->add('phone', 'collection', array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'allow_add' => true,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself:

The modification of the solution from the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762361/715660) that I made in order try to let it work for Symfony 3.3 needs to be differently:

```
/**
 *
 * @Assert\Callback()
 */
public function validatePhone(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if (/* Fields are not empty */)
    {
       $context->getValidator()->validate($this->phone);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution to an non-class form, what I've done is:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{        
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder
        ->add('status', TextType::class)
        ->add('invoice', SomeSubForm::class, [
            'required' => false
        ]);
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        if (!isset($data['invoice'])) {
            $event->getForm()->add('invoice', HiddenType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ]);
        }

    });
}
```

SubForm has NotBlank asserts on properties.